# Python 2 imp - ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to use the `imp` library to import a library my code looks like this:

```
import imp

PyPDF2 = imp.load_source('PyPDF2', '/Python Projects/econquizz/PyPDF2-master/PyPDF2/__init__.py')
pdfFileObj = open('./Chapters/Chapter-3_5.pdf', 'rb')
```

When I try running this code I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "brains_3.py", line 3, in <module>
    PyPDF2 = imp.load_source('PyPDF2', '/Python Projects/econquizz/PyPDF2-master/PyPDF2/__init__.py')
  File "/Python Projects/econquizz/PyPDF2-master/PyPDF2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pdf import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Does anyone have a clue on how this could be fixed?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to specify the package itself as your argument:

```
PyPDF2 = imp.load_source('PyPDF2', '/Python Projects/econquizz/PyPDF2-master/PyPDF2/')
```

Even better, put `/Python Projects/econquizz/PyPDF2-master` in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable and use a normal `import` statement (`import PyPDF2`).

---

---

*Followup:*

Here is a transcript showing how it can work, on my Ubuntu system:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/demonstration
$ cd /tmp/demonstration
$ wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b4/01/68fcc0d43daf4c6bdbc6b33cc3f77bda531c86b174cac56ef0ffdb96faab/PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz
$ tar -zxvf PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz 
$ export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/demonstration/PyPDF2-1.26.0/
$ python2
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyPDF2
>>> print(PyPDF2)
<module 'PyPDF2' from '/tmp/demonstration/PyPDF2-1.26.0/PyPDF2/__init__.pyc'>
>>> 
>>> help(PyPDF2)
Help on package PyPDF2:

NAME
    PyPDF2

FILE
    /tmp/demonstration/PyPDF2-1.26.0/PyPDF2/__init__.py

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    _version
    filters
    generic
    merger
    pagerange
    pdf
    utils
    xmp
[...]
```

You do not need to do this exactly as I did.  (in particular, don't do this in /tmp unless you really don't want to keep it!)  The key is to see the actual directory where I put the module, and see that I did put it in `$PYTHONPATH`, correctly, and that python was therefore able to find it and load it.

I did not read any instructions that the authors published about how to properly install it.  Some modules won't actually work correctly when run from source like I did here.  Some modules don't need any special installation and will work correctly in the form that their source is distributed.

Comment: PyPDF2-master is the same environment

Comment: @Fozoro I just updated my answer to show how it can work.  You'll need to provide specifics (not merely "it doesn't seem to work") to get specific help.